# Why is the parameter of this method a lambda and how does it work

Tags: ruby

Taken from Programming ruby 1.9 book:

```
def my_while(cond, &body)
 while cond.call
   body.call
 end
end

a=0

my_while -> { a < 3 } do
  puts a
  a += 1
end
```

produces:

0

1

2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method expects an explicit parameter `cond`, and this "condition" is assumed to be a lambda/proc (the assumption is made by relying on `cond.call` to succeed) and has to be passed to the method `my_while` explicitly. The `&` syntax captures a method's block (if present) in a variable by implicitly converting it to a `Proc` object ([see 'The ampersand'](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls)).

Blocks are not real objects in Ruby and thus have to be converted by using the ampersand syntax. Once the block is bound to a Proc, you can send the `call` message on it as on any other proc/lambda.

The `->` syntax is short for `lambda`, which converts a block to a Proc object (explicitly). There is also a slight difference between using lambda and Proc.new. Again, the wikibook:

> Actually, there are two slight differences between lambda and Proc.new.
>
> First, argument checking. The Ruby documentation for lambda states: Equivalent to Proc.new, except the resulting Proc objects check the number of parameters passed when called.
>
> Second, there is a difference in the way returns are handled from the Proc. A return from Proc.new returns from the enclosing method (acting just like a return from a block, more on this later):

```
def try_ret_procnew
  ret = Proc.new { return "Baaam" }
  ret.call
  "This is not reached"
end

# prints "Baaam"
puts try_ret_procnew
```

> While return from lambda acts more conventionally, returning to its caller:

```
def try_ret_lambda
  ret = lambda { return "Baaam" }
  ret.call
  "This is printed"
end

# prints "This is printed"
puts try_ret_lambda
```

> With this in light, I would recommend using lambda instead of Proc.new, unless the behavior of the latter is strictly required. In addition to being way cooler a whopping two characters shorter, its behavior is less surprising.

Comment: so the lambda is used just to be able to call it via cond.call inside the method

Comment: Yes - the first parameter `cond` is explicit and expected to be "callable" whereas `&block` is an implicit parameter, capturing the method's block.

Answer (score 2):

The piece `-> { a < 3 }` is a shortcut for a lambda term (which was introduced with ruby 1.9). This is the first parameter passed to your method (i.e. `cond`) while the block afterwards is assigned to `body`. The lambda is then executed inside your method via `cond.call`.