# Why this code become an infinite loop without using lambda as condition parameter

Tags: ruby, lambda

I'm reading Programming with Ruby 2.0 and have a question

```
   def my_while(cond, &body)
     while cond.call
       body.call
     end
   end

   a=0

   my_while -> { a < 3 } do
     print a
     a += 1
   end #=> 0 1 2
```

I so the question is: why we can not use the method this way

```
    def my_while(cond, &block)
      while cond
       block.call
      end   
    end

    a = 0
    my_while (a<3) do
      print a
      a += 1
    end #=> infinite loop
```

And actually how to use this function with condition (a<3) and a block parameter?

P.S. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945891/why-is-the-parameter-of-this-method-a-lambda-and-how-does-it-work) but still can't comment there to ask!

Comment: I don't know ruby, but I'm fairly sure `(a<3)` just evaluates to `true` and is passed to the function as value, not as a function that checks the condition each time.

Answer (score 1):

In the last code sample, `a<3` is evaluated when the line calling `my_while` is run.

As `a` has just been set to `0` in the line before, `a<3` evaluates to true (0 being less than 3). This means that inside `my_while`, `cond` is set to `true`. It continues to be `true` because `a<3` is never reevaluated, even though `a` is changed. Thus the `while` loop keeps looping.

Using the lambda and `.call`ing it on every iteration of the loop ensure that the condition `a<3` is evaluated for each loop, allowing the while loop to stop when `a<3` no longer evaluates to `true`.

Comment: mkay, thanks @Jakob s
do you know another way(except lambda and procs) to pass as a methods parameter condition NOT ITS VALUE?